# what are lookup rules when a name occured before function's declarator-id?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef int Name;
Name func(int){
  return 0;
}

int main(){
}
```

Consider the above code, I can't find a bullet in [basic.lookup.unqual] that can interpret how to lookup `Name` for definition of `func`. I will cite some potential rules here:

> 1. A name used in global scope, **outside of any function**, class or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global scope.
> 2. A name used in a **user-declared namespace outside of the definition of any function** or class shall be declared before its use in that namespace or before its use in a namespace enclosing its namespace.
> 3. In the definition of a function that is a member of namespace N, a name used **after the function's declarator-id** shall be declared before its use in the block in which it is used or in one of its enclosing blocks ([stmt.block]) or shall be declared before its use in namespace N or, if N is a nested namespace, shall be declared before its use in one of N's enclosing namespaces

Please note the emphasized parts, it seems that my case does not satisfy these bullets, because **Function definitions have the form**

> function-definition:
>
> > attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq(opt)  declarator virt-specifier-seq(opt) function-body

Let me analyze the first bullet. It says **outside of any function**,but according to the `Function definitions rule`, I think that `Name` is within the function(definition), bullet 1 isn't satisfied. Bullet 2 is similar with that of bullet 1. Bullet 3 says that the name used **after the function's declarator-id**, in my case, the `Name` is used before the function's declarator-id. So what's the rule about this case to find the unqualified name `Name`?

#### My confusions:

In my example ,the `Name`,`func` ,`(int)` and `{ return 0;}`(function body) are all parts of that function definition,So:

1. what is **outside of any function**,such as the `func` in my example,where's area of outside of that function?
2. what is **outside of the definition of any function**,such as the `func` definition in my example,where's area of outside of the definition of that function?

Comment: I would assume it comes under your points 1 and 2

Comment: @M.M Howerver,point 1 says that **outside of any function**,but `Name` used in function definition,point 2 says that  **user-declared namespace**,global namespace is not ,and also says **outside of the definition of any function**,obviously `Name` is in the definition of function `func`,So how to interpret that

Comment: The function declrator is not inside the function

Comment: @M.M  how to interpret this ,[[dcl.fct.def.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def#general-1),the function declarator is a component of function definition?

Comment: I would say it is comparable to: `C::type C::f() {/*..*/}` versus `auto C::f() -> type {/*..*/}` former look a global/namespace scope, whereas later at class scope.

Comment: @Jarod42  the keypoint of this questions is the definition of function ,according to `Function definition form`,the `declarator` is within the definition of function,so I'm confused by these bullet that refere to outside definition of any function.

Comment: @jackX Just to be sure, could you please clarify whether the question would be the same if you replaced `typedef int Name;` with either `struct Name { int etc; };` or `#define Name struct Unk*`. Also, if you replaced `Name func(int)` with `int func(Name)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I think that `Name` is within the function(definition), bullet 1 isn't satisfied.

Bullet 1 didn't say "function(definition)". It said "outside of any function". It doesn't specify declaration or definition; merely "outside of any function".

Since being inside or outside of a "function" is not a defined concept, it must be read as plain English. Is a function prototype "outside of the function"? Visually speaking, there's nothing special about a function prototype that is suggestive of an inside/outside distinction. By contrast, the function body's block scope does suggest an inside/outside distinction.

The *intent* of the text of course is quite obvious; it's talking about the function body. The rule equates "function", "class" and "namespace", all of which have a block that defines scoping for names. That is the most logical place for any inside/outside distinction, so it seems pretty obvious that it's saying that the global scope consists of everything that isn't in the scope of a function body, the scope of a class definition, or the scope of a namespace body.

So this can be easily handled with an editorial change.

---

Note that the committee recognizes the wording of this section (among others in that area) as [somewhat defective](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/3989), and there's a [proposal for rewriting it into something more coherent](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r4.html) in C++23. The new wording from the proposal completely rewrites this section.

Comment: so,`outside any function` means these areas that are not in function body,Right?then,what about `outside of the definition of any function`,I still don't understand it,If `outside of the definition of any function` means these areas that are not in function body,what the difference between `outside any function` and `outside of the definition of any function`?

Comment: Thanks a lot,I could not find the change content in the link,could you please cite part here in order that I can use them to search the whole change part

Comment: @jackX: You can't. You're going to have to read the *entirety* of the new text to understand it. The change addresses dozens of issues related to the various sections on declarations, so it's basically a near-complete rewrite.

Comment: Thanks,NicoBolas,I think I have to digging the further in these oceans :-)